# ionic 3 iOS platform with framework folders

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

When I remove/add my iOS platform with my ionic app, the remove deletes all my iOS framework/SDK files inside `platforms/ios/Frameworks` but re-adding the platform obviously doesn't restore them. Is this intentional? I believe I should be able to non-destructively remove and add a platform with Ionic. I end up in a situation where if I want to remove and add the iOS platform I have to restore my frameworks from source control.

Thanks,